# jQuery - inserts the row at the beginning of the table instead of at the end of the table

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I want to add newline in every loop I create in jQuery. I can see my values but when I try to insert the row it inserts it outside of the table. Where am I missing?

**My Blade**

```
<table class="table table-borderless" id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="skuAndName0"></span>
                </td>
                <td id="orderItemUnitPrice0"></td>
            </tr>
            <div class="tests0"></div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Script**

```
response[0].order_items.forEach((element,v) => {
    
    if(element.sku){
      $('#skuAndName'+[v]).html(element.sku+'<br>'+element.name);
    }else{
      $('#skuAndName'+[v]).html(element.name);
    }
    $('#orderItemUnitPrice'+[v]).text(element.unitPrice);
    
    var html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>';
    html += '<span id="skuAndName'+[v+1]+'"></span>';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '<td id="orderItemUnitPrice'+[v+1]+'"></td>';
    html += '</tr>'
    html += '<div class="tests'+[v+1]+'"</div> ';

    $('.tests'+[v]).append(html);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working link for the code?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have a `div` as a child of a `tr` element, and you cannot have a `tr` element as a child of another `tr` element. You need to fix your table structure in order for it to appear properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed it to td instead of div, I got the result I wanted and the final version is as follows:

```
<table class="table table-borderless" id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span id="skuAndName0"></span>
                </td>
                <td id="orderItemUnitPrice0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tests0"></tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**And I changed it to html instead of append.**

```
response[0].order_items.forEach((element,v) => {
    
    if(element.sku){
      $('#skuAndName'+[v]).html(element.sku+'<br>'+element.name);
    }else{
      $('#skuAndName'+[v]).html(element.name);
    }
    $('#orderItemUnitPrice'+[v]).text(element.unitPrice);
    
    var html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>';
    html += '<span id="skuAndName'+[v+1]+'"></span>';
    html += '</td>';
    html += '<td id="orderItemUnitPrice'+[v+1]+'"></td>';
    html += '</tr>'
    html += '<tr class="tests'+[v+1]+'"</tr> ';

    $('.tests'+[v]).html(html);
});
```